# Cannot display french accents in php mail

Tags: php, email, utf-8, character-encoding, iso

I have the following php script sends an email based on parameters returned:

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$headers  = "From: Source\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $to = $data["t_email"];
    $subject = "Hello";
    $message = (gather_post("locale") == "fr_CA")?"message français ééààèè": "english message";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I've taken parts out that are not relevent. The message will be sent out fine, but the accents will not appear correctly. Everything has been set as utf-8 charset, i don't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have to encode the html with utf8_encode().  For example:

```
$message = utf8_encode("message français ééààèè");
```

I have had to do this to dynamically import French Word docs, and it works great.  Let me know if this solves your problem.

### UPDATE (example working code)

```
<?php
$to      = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = utf8_encode('message français ééààèè');
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
echo 'success!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried adding utf8_encode, but it still doesn't give me the accents. I wonder if my problem is somewhere else in my document. Should I be making sure that my encoding is correct anywhere else?

Comment: As far as I know, with text, utf8_encode is all you would need.  I believe there is a different function you would have to run if you are pulling data from MySQL.  I've never actually tried sending french characters in email though.

Comment: oh ok, well I'm not pulling any data from my database. However, I am pulling a few data points form the $_GET variable. However, these data points don't have any accents, I wonder if they should still be utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Hmmm.  I just tested it, and utf8_encode worked for me.  Perhaps it depends on what email service you are using.   I'll update with my code that worked.

Comment: @bozdoz Can someone update the above example for java, i have same problem in java

Answer (score 3):

To resolve your issue you need to add the following line to your send email function:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Here is the integration of this line with an emailing function:

```
function send_email($to,$subject,$message,$fromemail) {

    $headers = "From: $fromemail" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $fromemail" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Errors-To: $fromemail" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    @mail($to,$subject,$message,$fromemail);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

See here good comments I found. Only this works for me.
https://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/

Details:

```
to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'Subject with non ASCII ó¿¡á';
$message = 'Message with non ASCII ó¿¡á';
$headers = 'From: example@example.com'."\r\n"
.'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers);
```