# PHP mail with accent

Tags: php, email, diacritics

I have a problem with sending email that contains a subject with accent. I've searched everywhere and all the solution doesn't work.

I have a string, the subject, probably encoded in **iso-8859-1**, sent via a command line script

```php
$res = shell_exec(sprintf("php mail.php %s %s %s %s",
   escapeshellarg($email->sender),
   escapeshellarg($receiver->email),
   escapeshellarg($email->subject),
   escapeshellarg($email->message)
));
```

And the header of the mail :

```php
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $endl;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . $endl;
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';
```

In result, I receive an email with ???? in subject

Note: tested in Windows, localhost

**Sample code**

*testmail.php*

```php
<?php
$sender = "me@gmail.com";
$receiver = "you@mgmail.com";
$subject = "Accentued éàèçô letters";
$msg = "Accentued éàèçô letters";

shell_exec(sprintf('LANG="fr_FR.iso88591"; php mail.php %s %s %s %s > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &',
                        escapeshellarg($sender),
                        escapeshellarg($receiver),
                        escapeshellarg($subject),
                        escapeshellarg($msg)
                    ));
?>
```

*mail.php*

```php
<?php

if ($argc!=5) exit;

$sender = $argv[1];
$receiver = $argv[2];
$subject = $argv[3];
$msg = $argv[4];

$endl = "\r\n";

//HTML header
$headers = "From: $sender" . $endl;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $endl;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $endl;
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';


 $msg = "
         <html>
      <head>
       <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
                $msg
      </body>
     </html>
     ";

$receiver = explode(',', $receiver);

foreach ($receiver as $rec)
{
    mail($rec, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    sleep(5);
}
?>
```

Execute: php testmail.php
Tested on Linux.

**SOLUTION**
The correct solution to this problem is to use base64_encode

```php
'=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719149/send-emails-with-international-accent-and-special-characters see bottom of the accepted answer.

Comment: **probably encoded ?** proper punctuation and accents relies on the encoding being used!! _probably_ isn't good! You need to know for sure what is the encode being used!

Comment: @peterbond: Tried. first it's not content type text/plain that I should use. Second, tried base64 encode but no luck. The problem lies around the command line encoding, in Windows, it's Windows-1252. In other system, it could be different.

Comment: @Zuul: it's come from a HTML form which is in iso-8859-1, so it must be iso-8859-1

Comment: Is the PHP file where you set the headers and send the email encoded with iso-8859-1?

Comment: Yes, would that mess up the result?

Comment: I had problems in the past with the email subject because the form/php file/variables/etc were not with the same charset! But, no, it does not mess up the result, in fact, it should be all on the same charset!

Comment: The problem here mainly because it goes through a Shell script. I just tested on Linux, the "???" when sent through Windows is replaced with "" (empty) when sent through Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after many tests with the updated code on your question, here is the working solution based on your current code:

**MAIL.PHP** <sup>(file saved with UTF8 encoding)</sup>

```
<?php

if ($argc!=5) exit;

$sender = $argv[1];
$receiver = $argv[2];
$subject = $argv[3];
$msg = $argv[4];

$endl = "\r\n";

// HTML header
$headers = "From: $sender" . $endl;
$headers.= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';

// Message
$msg = "
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    $msg
  </body>
</html>";

$receiver = explode(',', $receiver);

foreach ($receiver as $rec) {
    mail($rec, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    sleep(5);
}

?>
```

**TESTMAIL.PHP** <sup>(file saved with UTF8 encoding)</sup>

```
<?php

$sender = "inbox@domain.com";
$receiver = "outbox@domain.com";
$subject = "Accentued éàèçô letters";
$msg = "Accentued éàèçô letters";

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
shell_exec(sprintf('"LANG=en_US.UTF-8"; php mail.php %s %s %s %s > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &',
                        escapeshellarg($sender),
                        escapeshellarg($receiver),
                        escapeshellarg($subject),
                        escapeshellarg($msg)
                    ));
?>
```

I have tested this and received all mails correctly.

Comment: I tried it and still no luck, can you try to write a script to emulate this situation please? Actually, I used LANG="fr_FR.iso88591" . Tried utf8, \" , without ; , etc... but still not work. I use French keyboard to type accented letters

Comment: Update your answer with your full PHP code so that I can test it here!

Comment: @Thanh Trung, Just updated my answer with a working and tested update to your code!

Comment: The problem is probably because of my mail application. Tested on gmail and it worked... without the need of setting locale and lang. Escapeshellarg also causes a problem : it removes accented letters.

Comment: You need to take a deeper look to your application! The code on my answer works and sends properly the accented letters, using [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Consider using it to overcome encoding issues on your current method!

Comment: I tried your method, but I think the real issues is that the mailing application I used is not as good as Gmail. Plus the configuration of the server that execute the script, whether it allows you to change locale or not.

Answer (score 0):

The headers of the email need to be [RFC2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) encoded if they are not 7-bit US-ASCII.  The MIME declarations you already have cover the body, not the headers.

Usually, unless you are into learning how email works, the comfortable and correct solution is to find a library which properly handles this stuff for you.  I am not familiar with PHP, but this is a common question on StackOverflow, and the answers often seem to involve PEAR.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983965/cannot-display-french-accents-in-php-mail